# ng-repeat not updating after model changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

So we're developing this angular app with a firebase backend. I am having trouble with this particular function we're implementing. Basically what it does is every time a different option is selected, the showData() function fires to retrieve the relevant data from firebase (and it works). The problem is that the ng-repeat only updates on the first selection change. Successive selection changes are not reflected in the ng-repeat (although the data is retrieved and thus, the model changed).

View:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="dataController">
...
    <select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-change="showData()">
      <option ng-repeat="entry in transactions" ng-value="entry.serial">{{ entry.serial }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed">
    ...
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="entry in dataHistory">
        <td>{{ entry.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ entry.timestamp | date:"yyyy MMM dd 'at' h:mm:ssa" }}</td>
        <td>{{ entry.amount }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
...
.controller('dataController', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
    ...    
    $scope.showData = function() {
      $scope.dataHistory = [];
      transfersRef.orderByChild('serial').equalTo($scope.selectedOption).on('child_added', function(snap) {
        transactionsRef.orderByKey().equalTo(snap.val().transactionID).on('child_added', function(data) {
          var entry = {};
          entry = data.val();
          entry.id = data.key();
          usersRef.child(entry.fromUserId).child('name').once('value', function(nameSnap) { entry.fromUsername = nameSnap.val(); });
          usersRef.child(entry.toUserId).child('name').once('value', function(nameSnap) { entry.toUsername = nameSnap.val(); });
          console.log('entry: \n' + entry);
          $scope.dataHistory.push(entry);
        });
      });
    };
  }])
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try applying `$scope.$apply()` after `$scope.dataHistory.push(entry);` in your code.

This is because your array updating code maybe outside the angular digest cycle.

Comment: It's inside the controller no need for $apply  in fact it throws an error if applied.

Comment: Ok, have you tried console.log($scope.dataHistory) after a new entry is pushed? What does it show?

Comment: it shows a "premature end result" and i'm expecting this since data retrieval is asynchronous. It only lacks some fields but I don't think it should cause the view to not update.

Comment: @MywikiWitwiki do you still have this problem? Could you resolve?